# Command behaves differently in macro than by itself

Tags: macros, listings

I am trying to add comments to the left of a `listings` environment by following the suggestions shown here: https://zuttobenkyou.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/latex-saner-source-code-listings-no-starch-press-style/ using the command `\vbox{\llap{*\hskip 1em}}` inside of an escaped sequence.

But when I put the command inside of a macro it shifts the line over, while if I directly add the command there is no shift.  Can anybody explain why this is the case?  A MWE is shown below.

For background, `listings` allows you to revert back to arbitrary LaTeX code inside of a verbatim environment if you place the code inside of an escape sequence, which in this case is defined as starting with `(*@` and ending with `@*)`.  The `llap` command creates a box of width zero; the argument is then placed just to the left of this zero-width box (and hence will overlap whatever lies to the left).  I'm not sure what the point of the `vbox` command is.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*{\lnote}{
  \vbox{\llap{*\hskip 1em}}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, frame=single]
(*@\vbox{\llap{*\hskip 1em}}@*)echo hello
(*@\lnote@*)echo goodbye
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

When the document is compiled this is what it looks like.  The first line works as expected, and the second line is incurring an undesired horizontal shift.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your lnote command is adding space tokens. I commented them out of the definition here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\newcommand*{\lnote}{%
  \vbox{\llap{*\hskip 1em}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, frame=single]
(*@\vbox{\llap{*\hskip 1em}}@*)echo hello
(*@\lnote@*)echo goodbye
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

why a vbox here? Seems a very non-latex construct.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick, thanks!  I agree, I don't see the point of the vbox here, but I wanted to leave it in just in case it had something to do with the issue.